# ImportError: No module named flask.ext.security.datastore.SQLAlchemyUserDatastore

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Where i can find this module?

```
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.security.datastore.SQLAlchemyUserDatastore
```

Comment: Well, as you can see from the comments below, you're likely to be using the wrong Flask-Security branch. How did you obtain the version of Flask-Security you are using?

Answer (score 3):

It's in Flask-Security.

```
pip install Flask-Security
```

Also, it appears the example you're trying to run is erroneous, probably coded up to the API of an older version of Flask-Security.

Find the line in app.py which says:

```
from flask.ext.security.datastore import SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, \
    MongoEngineUserDatastore
```

And change it to:

```
from flask.ext.security.datastore.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyUserDatastore
from flask.ext.security.datastore.mongoengine import MongoEngineUserDatastore
```

I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/pull/31) for this issue.

Comment: And even there it is flask_security.datastore instead of flask.ext.security.datastore.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask-Social in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

and still ImportError

Comment: Flask-Security not Flask-Social.

Comment: i got it too: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask-Security in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: btw im trying to run https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-social/tree/develop/example

Comment: Tried to reproduce your problem and ran into a bug in the example app. See the edited answer, hope it helps you.

Comment: This is because you're using the example app from the develop branch. Look at the example app in the master branch. The master branch is what is available on pypi and when you install through pip. If you want to use the develop branch code, you need to install with pip as such: `pip install https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/tarball/develop`

Comment: Ah, yes that's right. Wonder why the cloned repo doesn't default to the mater branch... Thanks Matt!

Comment: No problem. Its because I have the default branch on GitHub set to develop. Maybe I should change that.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is REALLY old thread, yet even with 1.7.4 version (installed using pip) I ran into this error myself

The fix was to change this

```
from flask.ext.security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, \
    UserMixin, RoleMixin, login_required
```

to this

```
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, \
    UserMixin, RoleMixin, login_required
```

Essentially - change "flask.ext.security" to "flask_security"

Found this when I was going thru : http://simplectic.com/blog/2014/flask-todomvc-login/

Answer (score 1):

This is really old, but I was having a similar problem and the problem for me turned out to be that packages weren't installing correctly. I had to change `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` to `pip3 install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed` and it started working for me.